# Convert a tree to a forest where every component has an even number of vertices.

Tags: graph-theory, trees

I have the [following problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/even-tree), which I am struggling with. It asks to find the maximum number of edges to be removed from a tree to convert it to a forest, where every component will have an even number of vertices.

**Note**: The tree in the input will be such that it can always be decomposed into components containing even number of nodes.

> You are given a tree (a simple connected graph with no cycles). You
>   have to remove as many edges from the tree as possible to obtain a
>   forest with the condition that : Each connected component of the
>   forest should contain an even number of vertices.

I tried to tackle the problem for a reasonable amount of time and can not find a way to solve it. Can someone explain me the solution, and also how to come up with this solution?

P.S. I am not looking for a code here. I need someone with the knowledge of graph theory to explain me the logic.

Comment: You should probably add "Note: The tree in the input will be such that it can always be decomposed into components containing even number of nodes." to your question. I was confused because this problem cannot be solved for e.g. a tree with 3 vertices.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose that the tree has $n$ vertices; clearly $n$ must be even. Consider an edge $e$. Removing $e$ breaks the tree into two subtrees; either both subtrees have an even number of edges, in which case I’ll call $e$ an *even* edge, or both have an odd number of edges, in which case I’ll call $e$ an odd edge.

If you remove an odd edge, the resulting subtrees have odd numbers of vertices, and any further removal of edges will leave you a forest in which at least two trees have odd numbers of vertices; thus, you must never remove an odd edge.

It’s not hard to see that if you remove an even edge, each of the remaining edges retains its original parity in its subtree: if it was even in the original tree, it’s still even in its subtree, and if it was odd in the original tree, it’s still odd in its subtree. Thus, the resulting forest has the same number of odd edges as the original tree and one fewer even edge.

As long as there’s an even edge in your forest, you can remove it without producing a tree with an odd number of vertices, so you simply want to remove all of the even edges. (This is what was done in the sample on the linked page: the two edges that were removed were precisely the two even edges in the original tree.)

Comment: you mentioned that a Tree has n vertices and n must be even, how about these examples with trees of 1, 3, 5 vertices? http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Tree.html

Comment: @guilhebl: Of course there are trees with an odd number of vertices, but they’re irrelevant to the problem: there is no way to remove edges from them and get a forest whose trees all have even numbers of vertices. Removing edges does not change the number of vertices. Any forest, each of whose trees has an even number of vertices, has an even number of vertices altogether. Therefore the initial tree must have an even number of vertices.

Answer (score 1):

BFS to travel through the nodes. First, maintain an array separately to store the total number of child nodes + 1. So, you can initially assign all the leaf nodes with value 1 in this array. Now start from the last node and count the number of children for each node.
Once you get the array after getting the number of children nodes for all the nodes, just counting the nodes with even number of nodes gives the answer. Note: did not include root node in counting in final step.
link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12043252/obtain-forest-out-of-tree-with-even-number-of-nodes